# Transferência de chave primaria para chave estrangeira - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

estou tendo um problema ao inserir dados no meu banco. Tenho duas tabelas conectadas, empresa e informacões.

ESTRUTURA DA TABELA EMPRESA

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empresa` (
  `empresa_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empresa_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cnpj_UNIQUE` (`cnpj`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

ESTRUTURA DA TABELA INFORMACOES

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `informacoes` (
  `informacoes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_fantasia` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `descricao_da_empresa` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
  `inicio_expediente` time NOT NULL,
  `fim_expediente` time NOT NULL,
  `tipo_estabelecimento` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `foto_perfil` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `empresa_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`informacoes_id`),
  KEY `fk_informacoes_idx` (`empresa_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8
```

como podem ver, ambas estão ligadas através da chave estrangeira "empresa_id". Okay, meu banco está funcionando perfeitamente, porém estou encontrando problema ao vincular as chaves estrangeiras e primarias.

METODO SALVAR EMPRESA

```
public function salvar($empresa){

          try{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO empresa(email, senha, cnpj) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $empresa->getEmail());
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $empresa->getSenha());
            $stmt->bindValue(3, $empresa->getCNPJ());
            $stmt->execute();
            if(isset($stmt)){
              echo "<script>alert('Cadastro quase finalizado');window.location.href='../informacoes.html'</script>";
            }
          }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
          }

}



METODO SALVAR INFORMACOES

public function inserirInformacoes($dados, $name, $tmp, $size){

            $ext = end(explode('.', $name));

            $pasta = '../imagens-perfil';
            $maxSize = '1024 * 1024 *2';
            $permitir = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

            $name = uniqid().'.'.$ext;


            $sql = "INSERT INTO informacoes(nome_fantasia, endereco, descricao_da_empresa, inicio_expediente, fim_expediente, tipo_estabelecimento, foto_perfil, empresa_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt -> bindValue(1, $dados->getNome());
            $stmt -> bindValue(2, $dados->getEndereco());
            $stmt -> bindValue(3, $dados->getDescricao());
            $stmt -> bindValue(4, $dados->getInicioExpediente());
            $stmt -> bindValue(5, $dados->getFimExpediente());
            $stmt -> bindValue(6, $dados->getTipoEstabelecimento());
            $stmt -> bindValue(7, $name);
            $stmt -> bindValue(8, );
            $stmt -> execute();

            if(isset($stmt)){
                $upload = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta.'/'.$name);
                if($upload){
                    echo "<script>alert('Postado com sucesso');window.location.href='../index.html'</script>";
                }
            }

}
```

Como disse mais acima, meu banco está funcionando perfeitamente, entretanto não consigo recuperar o id criado na inserção dos dados na tabela empresa e joga-lo para a tabela informações como uma chave estrangeira. Lembrando que os dois métodos estão em arquivos separados.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174010/5878

Comment: Não deveria ser: FOREIGN KEY `fk_informacoes_idx` (`empresa_id`) REFERENCES `empresa` (`empresa_id`)?

Comment: Sim é verdade, esqueci de editar isso antes de postar a pergunta. Obrigado por me lembrar :)